# If two shape overlaps, how are the pixel determined in this html canvas jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pixel

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/526/

there is 2 strokeRect, one red other blue, at the part where it overlaps, if you do a mouse over, the pixel at the overlapped coordination is `(84,0,170) with respect to (R,G,B)`. Can someone explain how that pixel is calculated and if there is a way to disable or provide alternative blend equation?

Comment: I can't find your RGB(84, 0, 170) pixel, Dude.

Comment: @Jarrod : On the overlapped section, what RGB value is it showing for you?